# Protools 101 avid assessment

Tags: avid, pro-tools-9, test, best-practice

Hi guys thank you for the answer @TheFaderJockey (cool name!). 
I have the 101 assessment coming up and I wanted to know if it is possible to practice on a my protools 9 (at home), I'd obviously need a proper num pad-included-keyboard because I run it off a macbook pro.

Are there any really significant changes I should look out for besides the name change of "regions" to "clips"?

Answer (score 1):

Hey! I found an app for my iphone that's called "NumberKey"and it works perfectly, you only create a network or connect via wifi and your iphone becomes your keypad :). Plus it comes really handy when you need to record and you are far away from your laptop.

I hope this helps, and hope you have an iphone haha.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Is the assessment something different to the exam? I've taken the exam, which was just a multiple choice test of randomly selected questions across many subjects (such as MIDI, Audio, Editing etc.)

Comment: That's right. Unless Avid have changed the exam format, 101 is a MCQ test. If practice helps you remember correctly then by all means go get a numberpad. Else you just need to remember the default shortcut functions, and for the numberpad, it's the one that most people usually do not use. :D

Comment: ja it is the avid assessment, they have protools 10 at college 

Comment: no they havent changed it sorry, our class has little assessments leading up to the big exam. I'm just gonna practice is all :D

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to worry about any of the changes to Pro Tools.
You only do the exam for whatever course version you completed.

Your exam supervisor chooses the version when they are creating your exam account, so if you did the course in version 9, your exam will be in 9.

Comment: ja you see they have protools 10 there, i just wanted to practise at home cool thanks hey

Answer (score 0):

If you can, do version 10 of the exam so that you are bang up to date.

Comment: thanks, ja it will be ver 10, im just going to practise on 9 ;D

Comment: Mr Mcgregor, where could I get a hold of passed Protools10 exams to practice on? I've found one but it was 9 questions!